# Why does incrementing with CTRL-A in Vim take me from "07" to "10"?

Tags: vim

I have a series of numbers in Mac Terminal Vim which I am incrementing by pressing  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>. Strangley, when I am at `07`, the number skips up to `010` instead of `08`. I just tried MacVim and had the same behavior occur. Does anyone know why?

Note: Both Vim's work perfectly for `7`.

Comment: Hint: "08" is not a legal number in C/C++. Hint 2: "octal"

Comment: 07 = "7 octal" in many unix-y systems (and in JavaScript!) 7 octal + 1 = 10 octal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because a leading zero is a widely used notation for octal, in which the number that comes after 7 is 10. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_zero#0_as_a_prefix), “a prefix 0 is used in the C programming language, Python, Perl, the Unix shell bash, and other languages to specify octal numbers”.

Answer (score 46):

If you don't want to increment numbers in octal notation, `:set nrformats-=octal`.

Comment: see `:help nrformats `