# How to increment from 07 to 08 in GVim?

Tags: vim

It looks like using `Ctrl-A` in GVim doesn't increment from 07 to 08 since a prefix 0 is interpreted as [octal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273741/why-does-incrementing-with-ctrl-a-in-vim-take-me-from-07-to-10) by default.

How to make Gvim increment from 07 to 08?

Comment: Just found that the link you gave in the question has the same answer as mine. So why do you ask?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Command `:set nrformats-=octal` will do the trick. You can always use `:set nrformats+=octal` to restore `nrformats`. Or, if you don't like hex format either, you can just type `:set nrformats=alpha`. Alternatively, you can save this setting in .vimrc file if you'd like.