# Vim: How to count from "01" to "02" (not "01" > "2") in a function?

Tags: vim, numbers, sequence

I want to generate sequential file names that take the last 2+ digits
from current buffer's name and count upwards from there. Like this:
`08a01 > 08a02 > 08a03 > ...`.

The snippet I use ([thanks for initial advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457901/vim-adding-automatic-alphabetic-and-or-numeric-index-to-current-file-name), Ingo Karkat!) **leaves out the zeros**,
producing sequences like `08a01 > 08a2 > 08a3 > ...`.

```
if b:current_buffer_name =~ '\d\+$'
    let lastDigit = matchstr(b:current_buffer_name, '\d\+$')
    let newDigit = lastDigit + 1
    let s:new_file_name = substitute(b:current_buffer_name, '\d\+$', newDigit, '')
else
    let s:new_file_name = b:current_buffer_name . '01'
```

How can I tell Vim in a function that it should count upwards "with
zeros"? I tried adding `let &nrformats-=octal` before the
*if*-condition (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192064/how-to-increment-from-07-to-08-in-gvim)), but that didn't work.

Thanks for any explanations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

change this line:

```
let newDigit = lastDigit + 1
```

into:

```
let newDigit = printf("%02d", str2nr(lastDigit) + 1)
```

didn't test, but by reading your codes, it should work.

it hardcoded `2`, if your string was `foobar0000001`, it won't work. In this case, you need get the `len(lastDigit)` and use it in the printf format.

Comment: I was trying this solution but althought I remove `octal` value from `nrformats` option, it does the calculation using it. Try with a filename like `foobar004562`.

Comment: @Birei oh, thx, I neglected the `octal` thing! adding a `str2nr()` will fix it. answer updated.

Comment: btw, the option is for `c-a/x`, won't influence the `+` expression. @Birei

Comment: Yes. I was reading that section of the docs. It's a little confusing. I was expecting to work on every operations with numbers, but hey, we will have to deal with it :-)

Comment: @Kent works as expected, thanks very much, also for the comments. I have to look more into Vim's builtin functions (it feels "obvious" to find a `str2nr` somewhere in vimdocs now. :-).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to avoid doing the sum without `vim` taking into account that the number is not `octal` with leading zeros. I tried with `set nrformats-=octal` but neither it worked. Here is my workaround extracting the number in two parts, zeroes by one side and the other digits from leading zeros by the other side and calculate its length using `printf()`:

```
let last_digits = matchlist(bufname('%'), '\(0\+\)\?\(\d\+\)$')
echo printf('%0' . (len(last_digits[1]) + len(last_digits[2])) . 'd', last_digits[2] + 1)
```

Some tests:

With a buffer named `08a004562`, `last_digits` will be a list like:

```
['004562', '00', '4562', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

and the result will be:

```
004563
```

And with a buffer named `8a9`, `last_digits` will be:

```
['9', '', '9', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

and the result:

```
10
```

Comment: Thanks! I will use @Kent's solution as it is shorter. But yours is educational since I initially tried to figure out a similar workaround myself (extracting zeroes and other digits separately).